# Conditional rendering of useContext

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router-dom, use-context, react-router-component

The task requires me to fetch data from an API, based on target category groups.

For example, www.localhost:8000/women fetches all data corresponding to women, and www.localhost:8000/women fetch all data corresponding to men.

I have now created a common ContextProvider where data is fetched based on a value.

Please find the code below for better clarity.

```
export const ProductCategoryContext = createContext();

const ProductCategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

//conditional value which must be updated in onClick function of a <Link>.
  const [targetGroup, setTargetGroup] = useState("");

  const URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}`;

  async function getproducts() {
    console.log(targetGroup);
    console.log(123);
    try {
      if (targetGroup === "women") {
        const womensData = await fetch(`${URL}/women`);
        const jsonData = await womensData.json();
        console.log(jsonData?.items);
        setProducts(jsonData?.items);
      } else if (targetGroup === "men") {
        console.log(targetGroup);
        const mensData = await fetch(`${URL}/men`);
        const jsonData = await mensData.json();
        console.log(jsonData?.items);
        setProducts(jsonData?.items);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getproducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ProductCategoryContext.Provider
      value={{
        product: products,
        targetGroup: targetGroup,
        setTargetGroup: setTargetGroup,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductCategoryContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The code for the event handler is as below:

```
  const { setTargetGroup } = useContext(ProductCategoryContext);

 return (<Link
          onClick={() =>  setTargetGroup("women")}
          className="category-links"
          to="/create/women"
        >
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card_image">
              <img
                className="category-images"
                src={require("../../assets/images/women-tile-image.jpg")}
                alt="image for womens section"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>)
```

Now, the value of targetGroup remained unupdated because of which I am unable to fetch the data. I'm confused about what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, the `useEffect` hook is missing a dependency on the referenced `targetGroup` state value. The empty dependency array tells React to run the effect once on the initial render. Since the `targetGroup` initial state value is `""` nothing is fetched and then the effect isn't "listening" for any dependency to change to possibly refetch.

Add `targetGroup` to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array so when it updates the effect callback is triggered. Move `URL` and `getproducts` *into* the `useEffect` callback body to remove them as dependencies.

```
const ProductCategoryContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  //conditional value which must be updated in onClick function of a <Link>.
  const [targetGroup, setTargetGroup] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const URL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_HOST}`;

    async function getproducts() {
      try {
        if (targetGroup === "women") {
          const womensData = await fetch(`${URL}/women`);
          const jsonData = await womensData.json();
          setProducts(jsonData?.items);
        } else if (targetGroup === "men") {
          const mensData = await fetch(`${URL}/men`);
          const jsonData = await mensData.json();
          setProducts(jsonData?.items);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    getproducts();
  }, [targetGroup]); // <-- add targetGroup as dependency

  return (
    <ProductCategoryContext.Provider
      value={{
        product: products,
        targetGroup: targetGroup,
        setTargetGroup: setTargetGroup,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductCategoryContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

You may also find adding the [ESLint plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) for React hooks helpful. It will help you with missing dependencies and other general React hook issues.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did solve the problem!